# Reading xml from aspx web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, http, xsd

We have to read data from a aspx page. When we call the page with a query string, it returns an xml document with data that matches the query string.

We have an XSD that matches the xml that we get back.

I am thinking that we can read the xml document out of the http response. Will this work?

How can we *bind* the XML with the XSD, such that we can treat the XML document as if it were strongly typed?

Thanks,

Shiraz

**Update:**

Found this link on how to deserialize

[Deserializing XML to Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, basically, you can request an XML document something like this (no try/catch here - but you should definitely add that!):

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myRequest.Method = "POST";  // or GET - depends 

myRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=utf-8";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream reqStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
  // Send the data.
  reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  reqStream.Close();
}

// Get Response
WebResponse myResponse;

myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

using (Stream responseStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
   _xmlDoc.Load(responseStream);
}
```

Whether you have a GET or POST depends on your scenario - in a GET, you won't have request data going out.

Once you have your XML back as a XmlDocument, you can either validate that against the XML schema, or just try to deserialize it into the type that is represented by the XSD schema you have.

If that works --> the XML you got is valid and OK. If not, you'll get an exception on deserialization.

Marc