# .NET Parent/Child XML Deserialization Help

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have a XML doc with parent/child references that I want to deserialize into .NET objects but am unable to do so. Below is the XML snippet:

```
<family>
  <parents>
    <parent id="1" name="Sam" />
    <parent id="2" name="Beth" />
    <parent id="3" name="Harry" />
  </parents>
  <children>
    <child id="100" name="Tom">
      <parent id="1">
    </child>
    <child id="200" name="Chris">
      <parent id="2">
    </child>
  </children>
</family>
```

I want to be able to deserialize all the parent tags into the Parents collection using a .NET class as such.

```
class Child
{
  string Name;
  List<Parent> Parents;
}

class Parent
{
  string Name;
  int Id;
}
```

Any ideas? I tried `Deserialize` method on the `XmlSerializer` class but it only picks up the id attribute but does not relate it back to the parents node collection. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question posed here:

[Deserializing XML to Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c)

Basically since you stated the XML is hierarchical, you need to put the children indre the appropriate parent.  Try using something like this:

```
<family>
  <parents>
    <parent id="1" name="Sam" >
      <children>
        <child id="100" name="Tom">
          <parent id="1">
        </child>
      </children>
    </parent>
    <parent id="2" name="Beth" />
      <children>
        <child id="200" name="Chris">
          <parent id="2">
        </child>
      </children>
    <parent id="3" name="Harry" />
  </parents>
</family>
```

That way the children are "beneath" the parent nodes.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply but unfortunately i am not allowed to change the xml schema. i have to work with the format given.

Comment: Hmmm well with that limitation I am not sure the default deserialization will work.  How about as a workaround you use xslt to transform the XML to the schema I posted and then deserializing the transformed XML?