# Linq to XML, C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a multilevel xml that i receive from queues. I need to break each level and put into database. 
Below is the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
   <Request>
     <transactionID>3</transactionID>
       <units>
         <Number>001</serialNumber>
         <Id>222</instanceId>
         <fNumber>765</routeNumber>
         <status>open</status>
         <Message>Error</errorMessage>
       </units>
       <units>
         <Number>009</serialNumber>
         <Id>675</instanceId>
         <fNumber>765</routeNumber>
         <status>Close</status>
         <Message>mesage</errorMessage>
       </units>
     </Request>
```

I tried using ds.ReadXML... it only takes units beceause i give datamember property of datagrid to units

i need to put units into different table and transaction id also..
Pls help.

If

Comment: this Link might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: your xml is not well formed (i.e. <Number>..</sertialNumber> ?!) please fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to XML to navigate through the XML and break it down or  you might Deserialize the XML into a C# object 
Have a look at

[Deserializing XML to Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c)