# .NET XML Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following XML feed. I need to do deserialization to a `List` of objects. How can I achieve this in .NET 4.0 C#?

```
<body>
  <games>
     <sports>
       <lot_name>Football</lot_name>
       <prizes>
           <!-- For each prize the "division_" tag ends with different number -->
           <divisions_1>
              <divisions>1</divisions>
              <match>5-2</match>
              <pay>$10</pay>
           </divisions_1>
           <divisions_2>
              <divisions>2</divisions>
              <match>3-2</match>
              <pay>$5</pay>
          </divisions_2>
       </prizes>
     </sports>
  </games>
</body>
```

Comment: You won't get a collection; you'll get a single `body` object composed of a single `games` object composed of a single `sports` object composed of a single `prizes` object composed of a `divisions_1` object and a `divisions_2` object...

Comment: Is there a variable number of `<division_N>` tags? If so, can you use XSLT to change them to each be `<division>` instead? You're going to have a hard time deserializing to a class if the tags aren't consistent.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll - Why it will not deserialize?

Comment: @DavidBonnici in your original post you were missing the closing prizes tag. I've since amended my comment.

Comment: Ohhh sorry for that - Thanks :)

Comment: Your best bet here will be to change the `<divisions_1>` through `<divisions_n>` to just `<divisionelement>`.  This will make serializing to a List much easier.  This should be ok to do, since you have the `divisions` number as a sub element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c/226628#226628), a good explanation.

> xsd.exe is a handy little tool that comes with the .NET SDK (Software
>   Development Kit) that can make life easy when you want to quickly go
>   from an XML input to a strongly-typed .NET object.
>
> If you're starting with an XML file:
>
> 1) Open the XML file in Visual Studio
>
> 2) From the XML menu click "Create Schema". This will generate a XSD
>   file.

The rest [here](http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2007/07/generate-code-from-xml-schema-xsdexe.html).

Comment: The link provided to http://blog.stevehorn.cc/2007/07/generate-code-from-xml-schema-xsdexe.html no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [THIS](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) tutorial on how to do XML serialization, the example there is pretty near to yours.

Basically you need to create a class which represents each entity in your XML (e.g. `Sports`) and the corresponding properties and then us an XmlSerializer to deserialze it.

**The more complex way, but where you can handle the strange `<division_X>` tags, would be to use an [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9bfea29%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and read in the elements on your own and assign it to appropriate classes/objects.**

Comment: Not even remotely close, apart from both using XML. The issue is going to be with the variable `<division>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to generate a XSD with N `division_x` elements where x = [1..N] you have to implement `IXmlSerializable`.  The following code does deserialize the example xml nicely:

```
public class Sports : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string LotName { get; set; }

    public List<dynamic> Prices { get; set; }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        Prices = new List<dynamic>();
        reader.Read();
        LotName = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("lot_name", "");
        reader.Read();
        while (reader.Name.StartsWith("divisions_"))
        {
            reader.Read();
            var i = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("divisions", "");
            var m = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("match", "");
            var p = reader.ReadElementContentAsString("pay", "");
            Prices.Add(new { ID = i, Match = m, Pay = p });
            reader.Read();
        }

    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Games  {
    [XmlElement("sports")]
    public Sports Sports { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot("body")]
public class Body 
{
    [XmlElement("games")]
    public Games Games { get; set; }

}
```

It uses `XmlSerialization` because I am not quite sure how to do it with `Data Contract Serializer` (I know it can be done though). And you might want to add some error handling to the `ReadXml` method.

PS. You could do it with one class that implements XmlSerializer and emits a lot of dynamic classes :)