# Binding xml file to ObjectListview

Tags: xml, listview, data-binding, objectlistview

I have a simple xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tracks>
  <Track>
    <Name>Bye Bye Bye</Name>
    <Album>No Strings Attached</Album>
    <Artist>'N Sync</Artist>
    <Genre>Teen Pop</Genre>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Duration>00:03:20.6640000</Duration>
    <Location>\\psf\Home\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Music\'N Sync\No Strings Attached\01 Bye   Bye Bye.mp3</Location>
  </Track>
<Track>
```

I would like to bind it to an [ObjectListview](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). Anyone has any simple idea?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a class that represents the object.
2. [Deserialize the XML to the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp).
3. Populate a collection such as an array or generic list with the populated classes.
4. [Ensure that the ObjectListView has the appropriate columns with `AspectName`s set](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/getting-started.htm).
5. Call `ObjectListView.SetObjects()` to bind it to the collection.

Rough example:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(XMLFilePath, XMLFileName));
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassTrack));
ClassTrack MyTrack = (ClassTrack)x.Deserialize(sr);

// Deserialize other XML as necessary

List<ClassTrack> TrackCollection = new List<ClassTrack>();
TrackCollection.Add(MyTrack);

// Add other MyTrack objects to collection

olvTrackList.SetObjects(TrackCollection);
```

Comment: Hi Jyelton  as per your steps written the code please check the below stack question https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812923/thread/ee10ff57/