# Algorithm - create xml from structure

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have two tables in my database - Category and Food. Food has idCategory. Category has id and idParentCategory.

From them, I need to create a string which will look like this (or xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<tree id="0">
    <item text="Category1">
        <item text="Food1"/>
        <item text="Food2"/>
    </item>
    <item text="Category2">
        <item text="Category1">
            <item text="Food3"/>
            <item text="Food4"/>
        </item>
        <item text="Category3">
            <item text="Food5"/>
            <item text="Food6"/>
        </item>
    </item>
</tree>
```

How to create it? I tried finding the category which has id == 1, and then search all its children, but it's very complex. Is there an easy way?

One category can have many categories, but their children can have only food.

Comment: Have you tried writing a sql statement joining the data and then just dumping all the results into your string?

Comment: You want something to "look like this (not xml, but string)", but what you show is XML. why not show what you want? Where is your third table? what is the relationship between tables?

Comment: @jzworkman I write Linq which joins the tables but what good does it do?

Comment: Your question mentions three tables but you define only two, which do you mean?

Comment: @PeterMonks I later simplified it, but the word 'three' remained. I edited the question

Comment: @StealthRabbi I later simplified it, but the word 'three' remained. I edited the question

Comment: If you can represent what you want in Objects, it's fairly easy to serialize to XML.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv No to serialization. I have to do this with simple string/

Comment: @Bob2Chiv Ok then, but how to create the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize it from an object that has the structure you want; but you'll first have to create your object.

See: [Deserializing XML to Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp) 
if you don't know the object structure.

Once you have the object it's easy to serialize into an XML string:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(THEOBJECT));
        string THEOBJECTXMLSTRING;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, THEINSTANCEOFTHEOBJECT);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            THEOBJECTXMLSTRING = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return THEOBJECTXMLSTRING;
```

Comment: I know how to serialize an xml file. I don't know how to serialize THE xml file above.

Comment: So the problem is creating the object and hierarchy from the two tables, not creating the XML?

Comment: The problem is creating Xml like in the question.

Comment: I fear I do not understand. I have shown you how to create an XML string from an object that has the structure that you want (THEOBJECT). In order to use the method shown above you must 1. Create an object (THEOBJECT) that matches your hierarchy, 2. Populate an instance of the object (THEINSTANCEOFTHEOBJECT) with the data from the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off generating an XML document and trying to procure the byte information in order to transform it into a string.  Doing otherwise is not only time-consuming, but it's very error-prone.

Comment: Ok, how to produce xml file from this?