# Deserializing a complex XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a complex XML file which has several sub entities inside a main entity now i want to deserialize and map them to objects of the relevant classes

I'm using C# how do i do this?

Comment: Here's a tutorial using the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx): http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization Although the tutorial doesn't explicitly dive into sub entities, as long as the classes that your properties use are serializable, it will cascade through automatically.

Comment: Here's a link that explains how to do it. http://www.codingday.com/xml-c-class-generator-for-c-using-xsd-for-deserialization/ Basically you need to create a XSD file from your xml to serialize the xml to a class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use XSD.exe to generate a class for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.100).aspx

You can just pass it an XML file and it will generate the schema and create a class.cs which can be added to your project

This will be different depending on OS and version, but the exe is located at this location on my pc:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\