# How to read XML data dynamically in C#/.net?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How can i read XML data dynamically? How can I manage my C# code as generic and dynamic as possible? Based on the requirements I will need to add further folder paths in Xml, which should not affect the written code  in a way that it has to be rewritten..

Given a piece of XML as sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
  <HOSTS>
   <Host id = '1'>
     <Extension>txt</Extension>
     <FolderPath>C:/temp</FolderPath>
   </Host>
   <Host id = '2'>
     <Extension>rar</Extension>
     <FolderPath>C:/Sample</FolderPath>
   </Host>
 </HOSTS>
```

How can I read the host id dynamically? What possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ to XML.

Example: to retrieve host with (id = 1):

```
string id = "1"


XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var accounts = from elements in doc.Elements("HOSTS").Elements("Host")
                where elements.Attribute("id").Value = id
                    select elements.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes - in fact this is a very common task in C#.

There are a couple of ways you could tackle this:

- Use a library such as [XPath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333) to read the XML values
- [Deserialise the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp) into an object
- Load into an [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) object
- [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) (recommended)

Those links should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Generate an xsd scheme from that sample xml. Modify it as needed and then generate a strongly typed C# class using [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [System.Xml.XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class along with [System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w009fhk7) for constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Best way (for my opinion) for this case is use XML Serialization to strongly typed classes. You can control process with using [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.100%29).

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Hosts));
var hosts = (Hosts)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(str));
```

...

```
[XmlRoot("HOSTS")]
public class Hosts : List<Host> {}

public class Host {
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Extension { get; set; }

    public string FolderPath { get; set; }
}
```