# Data Abstraction to eliminate Switch usage

Tags: c#, xml, abstraction

This is a pretty abstract question, and I'm not necessarily looking for an answer or implementation, but rather some direction in terms of what approach  I might use or material I might read.

Essentially, I am creating a storage scheme for certain data in many different forms, one of the being XML.  When I load saved data from an XML file, I want to create user objects from the XML data.

I have an attribute within the XML hierarchy that provides a definition linked to the *type* of object that will be created; however, there are several different implementations of each type of object and I want to dynamically choose which object to create at runtime based on the elements nodes they provide and *not* have the user or anyone reading the XML worry or know about that.

As a result, my routine to parse the XML data has three steps:

(1) Parse all of the XML elements and save them as local variables

(2) Depending on which variables we gathered, instantiate the appropriate object

(3) Populate the object with the data

So, as a more concrete breakdown, my code ends up looking something like this (pseudocode, program written in C#):

```
// Object we're creating
GenericType object;

// Variables declarations
DURATION = "duration"
duration = 0;
...

// Step 1: Parse XML elements
switch(element.name)
{
  case element.name = DURATION:
    duration = element.value;
  case ...
}

// Step 2: Decide which object to instantiate, based on which variables were collected
// (variable analysis omitted for succinctness)
if(meetsRequirementsForObjectFoo())
  object = new Foo();
if(meetsRequirementsForObjectFooBar())
  object = new FooBar();
...

// Step 3: Populate object with data
Foo.setDuration(duration);
...
```

My question is what options/solutions do I have in terms of abstracting this data and eliminating some of the repetitiveness of this process?  In the end, I'm basically creating a new user object based entirely off of the elements in the XML file; the issue is that I don't know which object I want to create until I've essentially read all of the data.

I would appreciate any help or references to existing design ideas/patterns that might be useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a great candidate for the Factory Design Pattern. You could create a Factory that takes the XML as input (or the parsed variables, either way), and them decides which object to return based on that input, assuming the objects are all programmed to a similar interface. Otherwise, deserializing the XML to a class that matches the XML structure might be easiest and involve much less effort. See [Deserializing XML to Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely considered how I might implement the Factory pattern in this case.  All of the object types do extend from a common interface.  One of the main issues I am trying to avoid is reading in a list of random variables at one stage and then going through again and simply loading those into an object, two messy processes that I'm currently doing with string comparisons.

I'll definitely look into this Deserialization of XML to objects tomorrow morning.  I'll leave this open now to see if I get other responses, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Create classes that match the XML and then deserialize to those classes... Then if you really want to get away from that structure, use something like AutoMapper to map the values by property name and type to a custom class that you prefer?

Comment: After giving it more thought, changing the XML scheme to match the existing class names and serializing it seems perfect.  Thanks!