# Missing child nodes when deserializing XML to object

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have requirement to process certain xml, having trouble deserializing a list of objects from it. Following is the xml:

```
<catalog>
<item>
    <id>18338517</id>
    <note label="Name ">Gear xyz</note>
    <note label="Size ">10</note>       
    <note label="Source">Store xyz</note>
    <relation weight="100">
        <type>External</type>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>Mcday</name>          
    </relation>
    <relation weight="99">
        <type>Internal</type>
        <id>234</id>
        <name>Mcnight</name>
    </relation>
</item>
    <item> ..... </item></catalog>
```

Following is my class

```
[XmlRoot("catalog")]
public class Catalog
{
    [XmlArray("item")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(Item))]
    public Item[] item{ get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("note", typeof(Note))]
    public Note[] note { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("relation", typeof(Relation))]
    public Relation[] relation { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Note
{
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string label { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Relation
{
    [XmlAttribute("weight")]
    public string weight { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, calling to deserialize

```
Catalog catalog = null;
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Catalog));
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\TEMP\deserialize xml\catalog.xml"))
{
    catalog = (Catalog)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

It doesn't return any errors, just empty item in the catalog object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes, like you do here:

```
[XmlArray("term")]
[XmlArrayItem("term", typeof(Item))]
public Item[] item{ get; set; }
```

your XML has to actually provide the correct collection element. So your class should look like

```
[XmlRoot("catalog")]
public class Catalog
{
    [XmlArray("items")] // note that I corrected 'term' to 'items'/'item'
    [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(Item))]
    public Item[] item{ get; set; }
}
```

and your XML should look like

```
<catalog>
  <items>
    <item>
      <id>18338517</id>
       ...
```

Note the `<items>` element which corresponds to `[XmlArray("items")]`, and the children elements `<item>` which corresponds to `[XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(Item))]`.

If you don't want/can't change your XML format, use can simply use the `XmlElement` attribute instead of the `XmlArrayItem` attribute. So your final code should look like:

```
[XmlRoot("catalog")]
public class Catalog
{
     [XmlElement("item")] // no XmlArray/XmlArrayItem, just XmlElement
     public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("note", typeof(Note))] // no XmlArray/XmlArrayItem, just XmlElement
    public Note[] note { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("relation", typeof(Relation))] // no XmlArray/XmlArrayItem, just XmlElement
    public Relation[] relation { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Note
{
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string label { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Relation
{
    [XmlAttribute("weight")]
    public string weight { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I try to change the class and it works like magic :) thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

Your attributes are wrong:

```
public class Catalog
{
    [XmlArray("term")]
    [XmlArrayItem("term", typeof(Item))]
```

Try this instead:

```
public class Catalog
{
    [XmlArray("items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(Item))]
```

**EDIT**: For the further development of your project, you should consider creating an XML schema and **generate the code** using XSD.exe for example, see this question: [deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp/226628#226628)

**EDIT2**: Looking into MSDN, the  XmlArrayAttribute constructor is defined as:

```
public XmlArrayAttribute(
    string elementName
)
```

Where the parameters are documented as:

> elementName
>       Type: System.String
>
> ```
> The name of the XML element that the XmlSerializer generates.
> ```