# Using XmlTextReader to read attributes from element

Tags: c#, filestream, xmltextreader

In the code below, I'm finding the "Undly" element and then setting the appropriate attributes to a class.  Is that the correct way to do it?  Or should I be creating a new XElement class and then finding the attributes?

I'm still learning about the XMLTextReader and would like to use the best practices.

Also, I'm not sure if I should use the constructor that accepts the string (file path) to the XML file or use the constructor that uses the filestream.  It seemed like using the filestream had a faster performance.

Here is the code

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(RBMRBHTheoretical, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(fs))
    {
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (string.Equals(xmlReader.Name, "Undly"))
                {
                    occPLList.Add(new OccPL
                    {
                        Symbol = (string)xmlReader.GetAttribute("Sym").ToString().Trim(),
                        Description = (string)xmlReader.GetAttribute("Desc").ToString().Trim(),
                        Price = xmlReader.GetAttribute("Px") == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(xmlReader.GetAttribute("Px").ToString().Trim()),
                        Currency = (string)xmlReader.GetAttribute("Ccy").ToString().Trim()
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}

public class OccPL
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="4.4" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4 https://optionsclearing.com/components/docs/membership/dds_ref/fia_1_1/fixml-main-4-4-FIA-1-1.xsd">
 <Batch>
   <SecList ListTyp="109" ListID="20175" BizDt="2017-12-07">
     <SecL Ccy="USD">
       <Instrmt Desc="iShares S&amp;P 100 ETF" SecTyp="OPT" SubTyp="ETO" Sym="OEF" Mult="100.0">
         <AID AltID="00013" AltIDSrc="RBHP"/>
       </Instrmt>
       <InstrmtExt>
        <Attrb Typ="101" Val="1.0000"/>
        <Attrb Typ="108" Val="1.0000"/>
       </InstrmtExt>
       <Undly Desc="iShares S&amp;P 100 ETF" Px="117.110000" Ccy="USD" Sym="OEF" ID="464287101" Src="1"/>
       <Stip Typ="RBHMIN" Val="2.500"/>
       <Stip Typ="CPMMIN" Val="3.750"/>
     </SecL>
    </SecList>
  </Batch>
 </FIXML>
```

Comment: "*Is that the correct way to do it?*" Does it work? "*It seemed like using the filestream had a faster performance*" Without actual metrics, it's impossible to help with a perceived difference in performance.

Comment: Yes, it works.  I'll try to get metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an XSD for that XML in the FIXML element, I would probably generate a class from that XSD using the xsd.exe tool and deserialize to an instance of the generated class and pick out the bits you need for your own object.  [Deserializing XML to Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226599/deserializing-xml-to-objects-in-c-sharp)

Going the deserialization route is performant but rigid.  It will break if the XML doesn't match the schema.  XmlTextReader and LINQ to XML are usually a bit slower but more flexible in what they can handle.  If you're planning to handle a lot of arbitrary XML, what you're doing is fine.  If your XML is going to have a well defined schema, don't waste your time writing a bunch of custom deserialization code when you can use the XSD to autogenerate everything you need and use the deserializer.